# Connecting: Oracle Autonomous DB and R - ROracle package issue

Tags: r, database, oracle, connection, roracle

I'm trying to connect RStudio on a compute instance to the Oracle autonomous warehouse.
I've covered the following steps:

- Provisioned Autonomous Data Warehouse
  (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/tutorial-provision-adw/)

  - Stored the DB connection Wallet;
  - Installed Oracle Instant client basic package: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
  - Downloaded and placed in the same directory as the instant client: SDK package & ODBC package
  - included Instant package path in environment veriable PATH ("C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5") and create OCI_LIB64 system variable with the same path
  - installed GTools checking the PATH options
  - Extracted the wallet to: C:\oracle_client\instantclient_18_5\network\admin

Now I'm experience an inssue installing the ROracle package within RStudio.
I'm using the following script:

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5") 
install.packages("ROracle")
```

The error I got is the include headers have not been found:

```
Warning in strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) :
  unable to identify current timezone 'C':
please set environment variable 'TZ'
* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Oracle Client Shared Library 64-bit - 18.5.0.0.0 Operating in Instant Client mode.
found Instant Client C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5
found Instant Client SDK C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5/sdk/include
ERROR: cannot find Oracle Client include headers in C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5/sdk/include.
       Please set OCI_INC to correct location.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/Users/opc/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/ROracle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status
```

Everybody is saying to also set  OCI_INC like this (but I do not have a directory in the manner "...client_1/oci/include/:

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_INC="C:/Oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/oci/include")
```

Any idea what am I missing for the ROracle or in general?

R version: 3.6

Operating system: Windows Server on a compute instance

Comment: Are your headers in `C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5/sdk/include` or `C:/Oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/oci/include`?

Comment: And to be clear, this doesn't seem to be an issue with the package, as much as the user.

Comment: Hey, I'm not blaming the package - just asking for help. :) C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5/sdk/include is what I have from the SDK package. I do not have a directory like "... client_1/oci/include"

Comment: and for some reason the C:/oracle_client/instantclient_18_5/sdk/include folder is empty...  I guess this is not the way it should be

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.html#GUID-8C502BDD-C1A1-4EA0-9E88-D2F8452D4AC2) you need to download "Instant Client Package - SDK". When I checked the webpage for instant client the links for the SDK version were absent.

However,if you go here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html and select you O/S on the following page there should be a link for the SDK version. For example, I use a Mac and the correct download is here:https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/193000/instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip

Once I unzipped that file, the directory structure had an .../include folder with .h files that I think the installer needs to complete. Therefore, the correct settings on my Mac would be:

OCI_LIB64  set to /Users/keithlaker/Downloads/instantclient_19_3
OCI_INC set to /Users/keithlaker/Downloads/instantclient_19_3/sdk/include

One thing to note...I am not familiar with R but in broad general terms Oracle's in-database implementation of R (in-database R script repository and R object Datastore) that is part of the now free EE "Advanced Analytics" option is not part of Autonomous Database.

Therefore, your R project should be able to connect but you will not be able to use any of the usual in-database R packages because they don't exist.

Hope this helps.

Just found a thread on our internal forum which is worth sharing. The above might allow you to install the R client but ADB (ADW/ATP) does not support the use of  ore.connect() and ore.disconnect(). Support for R is on our product map, see this presentation from OpenWorld 2019 - https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1553766982670001yXnT/PF/CON4719%20OOW%20SF%202019%20-%20Hornick%20-%20OML%20Overview%20and%20Roadmap%20v1.4_1568740954169001k3Df.pdf